# Как вывести img в div в зависимости от выбора радио кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как вывести img в div в зависимости от того, какая радио кнопка выбрана?

```html
М<input type="radio" name='woman'> Ж
<input type="radio" name='man'>
<div>
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/877/PNG/32/male-profile-picture_icon-icons.com_68388.png" alt="">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/38/PNG/32/femaleuser_user_female_4515.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
.img-man,
.img-woman{
  display: none;
}

.man:checked ~ div .img-man,
.woman:checked ~ div .img-woman{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
М <input type="radio" class="man" name='gender'>
W <input type="radio" class="woman" name='gender'>

<div>
  <img class="img-man" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/877/PNG/32/male-profile-picture_icon-icons.com_68388.png" alt="">
  <img class="img-woman" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/38/PNG/32/femaleuser_user_female_4515.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ['https://icon-icons.com/icons2/877/PNG/32/male-profile-picture_icon-icons.com_68388.png','https://icon-icons.com/icons2/38/PNG/32/femaleuser_user_female_4515.png',''];
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((el, i) => el.onchange = e => document.querySelector('div>img').src = el.checked ? arr[i] : '');
```

```css
div>div{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div>
<div>М<input type="radio" name='gender'></div>
<div>Ж<input type="radio" name='gender'></div>
<div>ни мэ ни жо<input type="radio" name='gender'></div>
</div>
<div><img src="" alt=""></div>
```